# Windows 2003 Dedicated Server with MSSQL2000

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2003, windows-server

I am new to the world of dedicated servers and I want to build my own dedicated server using my old computer for educational purpose.

I am building a dedicated server for my old online game and I wonder how can I get the dedicated ip address. My server is Windows Server 2003 and MSSQL2000 for the database. The OS Server and Database is old and is not already supported by MS.

I already tested the game and now is working fine. All I want to know now is how can I get the static ip address to share it with my friends. Right now, the ip address I'm using is 192.168.1.5.

Comment: That's a local ip (for use behind your router). If you need a static ip, you need to ask your isp -- but consider using a dynamic dons service instead? You'll then need to configure your router to direct the traffic appropriately.

Comment: Both Windows 2003 and SQL Server 2000 are already past the end of life. You should really consider using modern versions -- and maybe a cloud service provider, it's probably a lot easier than setting up your own server.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. I need Windows 2003 and SQL Server 2000 for the gameserver files I have. It will not work in the latest version of servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static IP can't just be set up, but your Internet Service Provider might be able to assign one for you.

Better option would be using some dynamic dns service. This works so that your server (or router) will send your server's IP to the dynamic dns service every now and then so the service can then re-route some named address to that ip. You may then have a named address that points to your server like myveryownsuperserver.someddnsprovider.com

Not sure if it's the best, but at some point I used No-Ip as ddns since its free http://www.noip.com/free

Comment: I successfully register an account and and hostnames. When I access the IP / Target in my noip account it just send me to my router's login screen.

Comment: You are probably accessing your server from same network, through same router. Named addresses don't work in that case and you'll have to use computer name in your network. Try accessing your server from different network using that name you got from no-ip. If it still works the same (or not at all), you'll likely have to do some port forwarding to your router.